# R - Different approach to speed up 3 dimension array/matrix creation

Tags: r, matrix

My question is one of approach. Using SO I iterated through methods to create a 3 dimension array in R (this is my first question; R is a constraint). The use case is that this final array needs to be updated often but the two input arrays are updated at different periods. The goal is to minimize the final array creation time, but also intermediary steps if possible.

I know I can reach out with Rcpp, and I assign more than I need to for readability, but what I am wondering is:

**Is there a better approach to completing this operation**?

```
if (!require("geosphere")) install.packages("geosphere")

#simulate real data
dimLength <- 418
latLong <- cbind(rep(40,418),rep(2,418))
potentialChurn <- as.matrix(rep(500,418))

#create 2D matrix
valueMat <- matrix(0,dimLength,dimLength)
value <- potentialChurn
valueTranspose <- t(value)
for (s in 1:dimLength){valueMat[s,] <- value + valueTranspose[s]}
diag(valueMat) <- 0

#create 3D matrix from copying 2D matrix
bigValMat <- array(0,dim=c(dimLength,dimLength,dimLength))
for (d in 1:dimLength){bigValMat[,d,] <- valueMat}

#get crow fly distance between locations, create 2D matrix
distMat <- as.matrix(outer(seq(dimLength), seq(dimLength), Vectorize(function(i, j) distCosine(latLong[i,], latLong [j,]))))

###create 3D matrix by calculating distance between any two locations;
# create 2D matrix from each column in original 2D matrix
# add this column-replicated 2D matrix to the original
bigDistMat <- array(0,dim=c(dimLength,dimLength,dimLength))
for (p in 1:dimLength){
  addCol <- distMat[,p]  
  addMatrix <- as.matrix(addCol)
  for (y in 2:dimLength) {addMatrix <- cbind(addMatrix,addCol)}
  bigDistMat[,p,] <- data.matrix(distMat) + data.matrix(addMatrix)}

#Final matrix calculation
bigValDistMat <- bigValMat / bigDistMat
```

...as context this is part of a two step ahead forecast policy developed for a class using Barcelona Bikesharing (Bicing) data. The project is over and I am interested how I could have done better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you want to speed up your code you want to identify bottle necks and fix them like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28674397/1174052). Putting all your code before hand in a function would
Be a good idea.

In your specific case, you use much too much for loops for an R code. You need to vectorize your code much more.

**Edit**
Now for the long answer:

```
    #simulate real data, you want them to be random
    dimLength <- 418
    latLong <- cbind(rnorm(dimLength,40,0.5),rnorm(dimLength,2,0.5))
    potentialChurn <- as.matrix(rnorm(dimLength,500,10))

    #create 2D matrix, outer is designed for this operation
    valueMat <- outer(value,t(value),FUN="+")[,1,1,]
    diag(valueMat) <- 0

    # create 3D matrix from copying 2D matrix, again, avoid for loop
    bigValMat <- array(rep(valueMat,dimLength),dim=c(dimLength,dimLength,dimLength))
    # and use aperm to permute the dimensions
    bigValMat <- aperm(bigValMat2,c(1,3,2))

    #get crow fly distance between locations, create 2D matrix
    # other packages are available to compute that kind of distance matrix
    # but let's stay in plain R
    # wordy but so much faster (and easier to read)
    longs1 <- rep(latLong[,1],dimLength)
    lats1 <- rep(latLong[,2],dimLength)
    latLong1 <- cbind(longs1,lats1)
    longs2 <- rep(latLong[,1],each=dimLength)
    lats2 <- rep(latLong[,2],each=dimLength)
    latLong2 <- cbind(longs2,lats2)
    distMat <- matrix(distCosine(latLong1,latLong2),ncol=dimLength)

    ###create 3D matrix by calculating distance between any two locations;
    # same logic than for bigValMat
    addMatrix <- array(rep(distMat,dimLength),dim=rep(dimLength,3))
    distMat3D <- aperm(addMatrix,c(1,3,2))
    bigDistMat <- addMatrix + distMat3D

    #get crow fly distance between locations, create 2D matrix
    #Final matrix calculation
    bigValDistMat <- bigValMat / bigDistMat
```

Here it is 25x faster than your initial code (76s -> 3s). It could still be much improved but you got the idea: avoid `for` and `cbind` *and co* at all costs.

Comment: Amazing thanks. Didn't know about aperm, how to build a 3d array with 2d matrixes or filling up a matrix as above with distMat - extremely useful.